# Pandas - append() rows to original DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, append, concatenation

Both `concat()` and `append()` modify a copy of a Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 4));
df = pd.concat(df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1, 4)));
# or 
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1, 4)));
```

I want to be able to add new rows to the original dataframe within a list comprehension, such as:

```
# this list is for example's sake. In reality, the list numbers are rows 
# that I generate on the row
item_list = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1, 4)), pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1, 4)), pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1, 4))]
df_with_new_rows = [df.append(item) for item in item_list]
```

But obviously,  `df_with_new_rows` is identical to `df` and does not have any of the rows within the `item_list` added. How can I achieve this?

I did check the [Pandas manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) but could not find a way.

Comment: why do does it matter if its the original or not, just reassign the returned dataframe to the original (as you have done). Why difference does it make?

Comment: @Jeff `[df = df.append(item) for item in item_list]` does not work. How do I reassign the returned dataframe to the original within a list comprehension? Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: ``df = pd.concat([ df, *list_of_dfs ])``

Comment: `df= pd.concat([df, *item_list])` gives an invalid syntax error. `df= pd.concat([df, item_list])` gives this `error: 'list' object has no attribute '_data'`

Comment: Try df = pd.concat(item_list)

Comment: you have to use the ``*``, you pass a list-of-dataframes to concat

Comment: Thanks both, `pd.concat(item_list)` actually worked in my case since I start with df=empty dataframe in the beginning. still do not know how to use `*`, I get the error above. Will google it.

Comment: you don't need an empty dataframe at all; just do ``df=pd.concat(item_list)``.

Comment: I think the complaint is more that whenever any operation is done append, concat, ... it does not do it in place but returns a df instead. This makes it hard for in-place operations like done with list comprehension. I agree it's a pain; however, I am currently unaware of any in-place operation.

Comment: If you have passed a df into a function and are appending it in there and cannot return back the df, then the original df remains unchanged. We really need a `inplace=True` option here.